# Overflow: hidden works differently in Firefox and Opera?

Tags: html, css, opera

I'm having trouble with the overflow: hidden property in Opera/Chrome. (It is working as intended in Firefox)
Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/w7mj32kv/6/
Using Firefix will allow me to click the table cells and the text will show up in the bottom row of the table. On the other hand, none of that works in Opera. I'm not sure about Chrome as I don't have it installed, but I assume it will behave the same way as Opera.

```
overflow: hidden;
```

edit: I've updated the link. It turns out Opera is only malfunctioning if I set the div's width and height to 100%. If I set a fixed value, it works....
Does this mean Opera/Chrome + overflow: hidden + width: 100% doesn't mix? :(

Comment: I'd suggest you to check the MDN concerning overflow, it contains a compatibility table on the problem. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow). What version of Firefox and Opera/Chrome are you running ?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of both FF and Opera.